# defpartial returning object instead of HTML string

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am using Chris Ganger's crate library to generate html on the client side.

```
(defpartial html [] form)

(def form 
  [:div.form-horizontal
   [:fieldset
    [:legend "Student Registeration"]
    [:div.control-group
     [:label.control-label "Hello World"]]])
```

When I execute the above function in in clojurescript repl `(html)` I get `#<[object HTMLDivElement]>.`

However when I execute it as `(.log js/console (html))`, the proper generated html is logged into the browser's console.

How do I get it to return a HTML string instead of an object?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is an Dom Element object for the DIV element. You can use "outerHTML" property of this DOM element to get its string representation.

Comment: Thanks Ankur !! Also is there is a way to inspect its properties in the repl ? Or how do I print all the properties of the DOM object ?

Comment: I guess you can use all the typical DOM API method like `getAttributes` on DOM elements